# Getting a cache to update variable every half hour on the hour

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have a .net application variable cached.  What I want to do it get the cache to recycle the variable every half hour on the hour, 1, 1.30, 2, 2.30 etc.  I have the onRemoveCallback function set and everything works, my real question is what is the best way to generate the correct absoluteExpiration value?

```
DateTime time_to_expire = DateTime.Now;
            if (time_to_expire.Minute < 29)
            {
                time_to_expire = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, 30, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                time_to_expire = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour + 1, 0, 0);
            }
```

The reason I test the time_to_expire value to 29 is that I am worried about boundary cases and I don't want the variable to 'go blank' for a half hour period!  Ideas on how to do this better?

Thanks

Comment: If your on remove callback is working, the variable won't go blank. Worse case should be that the callback function gets called again if you hit the edge case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know that it is any "better" but I would be inclined to do something like this:

```
        DateTime time_to_expire = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
        time_to_expire = new DateTime(time_to_expire.Year, time_to_expire.Month, time_to_expire.Day, time_to_expire.Hour, time_to_expire.Minute >= 30 ? 30 : 0, 0);
```

Comment: What about midnight?  That's the problem the rolling day value.

Comment: Yeah I see, adding the half an hour first rolls it around which takes care of the midnight issue, thanks I think that will work.